# Java: Convert an applet to a desktop application

Tags: java, applet

So far I've only seen ways to convert Java desktop applications to applets. Is there any way to do the reverse? (it inherits from `java.applet.Applet`)

Edit: What I meant was to somehow make an applet a desktop executable JAR file (swing or something).

Comment: What do you need to convert?
How much code does it inherit from Applet, you need to change it so it uses JPanel, JFrame.

Comment: Convert's a bad word. What I meant was to somehow make an applet a desktop executable JAR file (swing or something).

Comment: Is it code you've written? If it inherits from Applet, it is then an AWT application, and your best bet is to re-write it as a Swing application with your goal being to create a JPanel that can be used in a JApplet or JFrame as the need dictates.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to run it in some sort of AppletViewer

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/appletviewer.html

Here is a similar question.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/188982/how-to-run-an-applet-like-a-desktop-application-without-installing-entire-jdk

Hope it helps.

Failing which you will need to re-base the code on JFrame and java Swing

Answer (score 1):

Without any (example) code it's difficult to pin point an example.

However, the general approach is to contain all your application logic and GUI code in a separate package/classes. By containing your basic UI in something like a JPanel, you can chose where to place it.

This not only means you can switch it out into a `JApplet` or `JFrame`, but also include it as part of a compound UI as required

This is one of the reason why we suggest not adding/building your UI directly on top of a top level container